# How to display all images in same marquee?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Here is my code:

Now i want adjust all images in same marquee

[image]

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from event_extra_img where event_id=9");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $image=$row ['event_img_path'];
    echo '<div style="margin-right:350px;">';
    echo '<marquee><img src="upload/extra/'.$image.'" width="100" height="100"></marquee>.&nbsp;';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

?>

Comment: I think you should first watch http://articles.tryonee.com/articles/2/PDO-for-Beginner

Comment: You want all images in the same `<marquee></marquee>`? Have you tried removing it from inside your `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))` loop, and wrapping your loop -> `echo '<marquee>';while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){..[your code]..} echo '</marquee>';`

Comment: please update your code with changes said by @Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
echo '<div style="margin-right:350px;">'; 
echo "<marquee>";

$sql=mysql_query("select * from event_extra_img where event_id=9");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $image=$row ['event_img_path'];

    echo '<img src="upload/extra/'.$image.'" width="100" height="100">.&nbsp;';

 }

echo "</marquee>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: I get images from database.

Comment: there is problem with your image size or with the div...i showed that it is working..